# GeneXus - GXFlow : How to retrieve username of the user

Tags: business-process-management, genexus

I'm working with GeneXus and I'm trying to create a Business Process Diagram for GXFlow.
I need to read the logged user's username.
I've tried to read the &WorkflowUser.Name variable but it doesn't work.
How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the same problem, this is the solution:

http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?10645,HowTo%3A+Getting+Logged+User